# Proof for the logarithmic reciprocal property

Tags: logarithms

I was wondering if anyone has a proof for the logarithmic reciprocal property:

$\frac{1}{log_a(b)}=log_b(a)$

Thanks in advance, I sat down and tried to prove it myself but I couldn't do it and I haven't found any proof for this specific property online.

Answer (score 1):

The change of base formula says that
$$\log_a(b) = {\log_c(b)\over \log_c(a)},$$
for any base $c > 0$.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how the reciprocal ties into this.

Comment: Set $c=a.$ Done.

Comment: I did and that just leaves me with $log_a(b)=\frac{log_a(b)}{log_a(a)}$ which simplifies to $log_a(b)=\frac{log_a(b)}{1}=log_a(b)$

Comment: @finnbratfisch  Set $c=b$.  Note: $$\begin{align}b&=b\\
a^{\log_a b}&=b\\
\left(c^{\log_c a}\right)^{\log_a b}&=c^{\log_c b}\\
c^{(\log_c a)(\log_a b)}&=c^{\log_c b}\\
\therefore\quad (\log_c a)(\log_a b)&=\log_c b
\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes, I see now. When $c=b$ this equation can be written as $(log_c(a))(log_a(b))=log_b(b)=1$. Dividing by $log_a(b)$ leaves you with $log_c(a)=\frac{1}{log_a(b)}$. Because $c=b$ this can be written as $log_c(a)=\frac{1}{log_a(c)}$. Thank you very much!